# POS for .NET Known Service Objects

Tags: .net, point-of-sale, pos-for-.net

I was wondering if anyone knew where I could find a list of LineDisplays, CashDrawers, Printers, that work well with POS for .NET.  I want to get around creating my own service objects for potential devices that I might by which are not supported.  Thanks.

Comment: I've been having a difficult time searching for some good documentation on POS devices. If you've run into some, please do share with me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Epson OPOS ADK for Pos .Net, you'll find it contains a readme.txt file which specifically lists the Epson hardware they support. To download this you need to create an account at www.epsonexpert.com, login, go to application development -> opos and then scroll to the bottom of the page to find the .net downloads.

Also, Sean Limings site might help; http://www.seanliming.com/WEPOS.html

He has some information posted about vendors providing SO's.

Also, TPG (sometimes rebranded as HP) have compatible OPOS objects for cash drawers and printers, but they don't have native service objects, and their OPOS service objects don't work when you are logged onto Windows as a non-admin user.

Answer (score 0):

A number of vendors, including Epson, provide native .NET service objects.  Also, keep in mind that POS for .NET supports legacy OPOS for all of the device categories listed above.